# How to ask "Are you sure?" before close JInternalFrame?

Tags: java, swing

I made a java swing application with JInternal frames. When I close a internal frame, it should show a pop message "Are you sure?" in a Option pane. How can i put event in the close operation of JInternal frame? Please help me.

Comment: Take a look at [InternalFrameListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/event/InternalFrameListener.html)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/internalframelistener.html for information on how to write an `InternalFrameListener`. You can put all your code for the closing inside the `internalFrameClosing(InternalFrameEvent e)` method.

Then, simply add a new instance of your newly created `InternalFrameListener` to your `JInternalFrame` with the `JInternalFrame` method `addInternalFrameListener`, as you can see on the previous link.

Here's information on the `addInternalFrameListener` method: [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JInternalFrame.html#addInternalFrameListener%28javax.swing.event.InternalFrameListener%29)

Code:

```
public class InternalFrameEventDemo implements InternalFrameListener{
    JInternalFrame frame;
    public InternalFrameEventDemo() {
        frame = new JInternalFrame("Event Generator",
                                                      true,  //resizable
                                                      true,  //closable
                                                      true,  //maximizable
                                                      true); //iconifiable
        //so that you can decide whether to close it or not
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JInternalFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.addInternalFrameListener(this);
    }
    public void internalFrameClosing(InternalFrameEvent e) {
        //YOUR CODE HERE
        int option = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Really Close?", "Exit", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);  
        if (option == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){
            //call dispose to really close it
            dispose();  
        }  
    }
    public void internalFrameClosed(InternalFrameEvent e) {

    }
    public void internalFrameOpened(InternalFrameEvent e) {

    }
    public void internalFrameIconified(InternalFrameEvent e) {

    }
    public void internalFrameDeiconified(InternalFrameEvent e) {

    }
    public void internalFrameActivated(InternalFrameEvent e) {

    }
    public void internalFrameDeactivated(InternalFrameEvent e) {

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new InternalFrameEventDemo();
    }
}
```

Comment: Not a problem, good luck with your implementation.

Comment: Is there a reason why you used a Listener, and not a Adapter?